# What am I doing wrong in cart in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement shopping cart in angularJS using localstorage. here is my code link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt1yr20zili46uw/shipping_cart_v1.rar?dl=0
My problem is when i add new item(s) these items still bind with text boxes. I know i am not defining my problem clearly. So that i share my code link you can check this problem.

This is just first try so each and every improvement suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: There are better ways to share your code.

Comment: Please use jsfiddle.net to share your code. You can post your js, HTML, and include external libraries (like angular...which you'll need to do). Not many people are going to be downloading your rar I'd guess.